# Pandas aggregate - Counting values over x

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm playing around with a data set and everything is sailing smoothly. I'm currently having an issue with generating a count of values over the value of 0.

What I have is:

```
zz = g.aggregate({'Rain':['sum'],'TotalRainEvent':['max'],'TotalRainEvent':['count']})
print(zz)
```

Which returns:

```
                 Rain TotalRainEvent
              sum          count
Year Month                      
2010 1        0.0             31
     2        4.8             28
     3       27.8             31
     4       30.6             30
     5       89.8             31
          ...            ...
2020 2       11.0             29
     3       40.9             31
     4       11.1             30
     5      107.3             31
     6       46.4             22

[126 rows x 2 columns]
```

As you can see the count value is returning the number of records in the month. I'm only wanting to count values that are greater than 0.

I'm able to create a count by creating another column and simply entering a 1 in there if there's a value in the 'TotalRainEvent' column, but I think it'd be better to learn how to manipulate the .aggregate function.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you do `g = g.replace(0,np.nan)` at the beginning and `g = g.replace(np.nan, 0)` at the end? I don't think np.nan values will be counted, per documentation.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html

```
g = g.replace(0,np.nan)
zz = g.aggregate({'Rain':['sum'],'TotalRainEvent':['max'],'TotalRainEvent':['count']})
zz = zz.replace(np.nan, 0)
g = g.replace(np.nan, 0)
```

print(zz)

Comment: Thanks, was able to get it working pretty easily with this. Was hoping to find a way to count conditions but that doesn't seem possible with the aggregate function, so this worked great!